# Is 7 a congruent number?

Tags: number-theory

I have a problem with understanding congruence of number 7.

The idea is such as: **Which integers can occur as the common
difference between three rational squares that form an arithmetic
sequence?**

That integer number is congruent

In book I'm reading that : **To prove 7 is congruent, observe that $\frac{24}{5}^2,\frac{35}{12}^2, \frac{337}{60}^2$ have common difference 7**

But it dosen't work.

For instance:
$$\frac{337}{60}^2 - \frac{24}{5}^2 = 8.506944444$$

I will be grateful for explaining Best regards

Comment: The three given form a Pythagorean triple ; $$\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{35}{12}\right)^2  = \left(\frac{337}{60}\right)^2  $$ I don't know  where the number $7$ comes from.

Comment: The right triangle with sides $\{\frac {35}{12}, \frac {24}5, \frac {337}{60}\}$ does indeed have area $7$....which makes $7$ a congruent number.  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: The $\;7\;$ being a congruent number comes from the fact that $\;7\;$ is the area of a right triangle with rational sides: precisely the one whose sides are the given numbers.

Comment: @lulu: What is the connection between your comment (involving area) and the OP's question (containing his own definition of "congruent numbers")?

Comment: The question **does not** contain any definition of the OP of congruent number. It just says that *in order to prove that 7 is a congruent number, **observe that** ...* etc., perhaps as a middle step or something.

Comment: @AlexM.  I have no guess as to what the OP thinks a congruent number is. Certainly, no alternate definition appears in the post.  But it is a defined term and the fractions introduced are precisely those needed to prove that $7$ satisfies the widely accepted definition, so I'm sticking with that.

Comment: What you really need to consider is $x=(337/120)^2$. Then $x-7,x,x+7$ have common difference $7$, and are rational squares. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

The number $\;7\;$ is congruent since

$$\frac{\frac{24}5\cdot\frac{35}{12}}{2}=7\;,\;\;\text{ and}\;\;\frac{24}5\,,\;\;\frac{35}{12}\;,\;\;\frac{337}{60}\;$$

are the sides of a right triangle with legs' lengths the first two numbers above, and hypotenuse of length the last number.

Adding the info gathered in the comments: putting

$$a=\frac{24}5\;,\;\;b=\frac{35}{12}\;,\;\;c=\frac{337}{60}$$

we then must consider

$$A:=\frac{a-b}2=\frac{113}{120}\;,\;\;B:=\frac c2=\frac{337}{120}\;,\;\;C:=\frac{a+b}2=\frac{463}{120}$$

and now:

$$B^2-A^2=\frac{113,569-12,769}{14,400}=7=\frac{214,369-113,569}{14,400}=C^2-B^2$$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Indeed so. :)

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the definition the OP quoted: "Which integers can occur as the common difference between three rational squares that form an arithmetic sequence?"

Comment: I, too, don't see the connection between this answer and the OP's question.

Comment: The question's title is clear, I think: "Is 7 a congruent number?", and this answer addresses and answers that. What the OP quotes as said by who knows what book doesn't matter (to me, at least), because as the OP himself showed, it is *not* true those squares have common difference $\;7\;$ ...and even if they did I don't really know what that would have to do with the congruent numbes problem.

Comment: Yes.  It's exactly the same problem.  It's also the same problem as finding rational points on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$, where $n$ is a congruent number.

Comment: @B.Goddard Ah, about the points on that elliptic curve I can follow. Yet the difference isn't what the OP says it should be. I don't really know what happened there (in class, in that book...)

Comment: @DonAntonio  Sorry, yes, the statement of the problem has an error.  If $a, b, c$ are the sides of a primitive Pythagorean triangle with integer area, then the arithmetic progression of squares is given by the squares of $(a-b)/2$, $c/2$, $(a+b)/2$.  If we put the fractions given into these formulae and square them, the common difference is 7.

Comment: @B.Goddard AH, that's very nice. Thanks...and also thanks in the OP's name.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make an answer out of my comment:  The statement of the question is in error.  The construction is that if $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ and $n = ab/2$, (so that $n$ is a congruent number) then one can construct an AP of squares via $(a-b)/2$, $c/2$, $(a+b)/2$.  So in this case $(a-b)/2 = 113/120$, $c/2 = 337/120$ and $(a+b)/2 = 463/120$.  Then $$\left({113\over 120}\right)^2 -\left({337\over 120}\right)^2 = 7$$ and $$ \left({463\over 120}\right)^2 -\left({113\over 120}\right)^2= 7$$

Comment: Yep.  Stand by. a

Answer (score 1):

In general, $n$ is a congruent number if and only if there exists a rational number $x$ such that $(x,x-n,x+n)$ is a triple of squares of rational numbers. 
So $x-n$, $x$ and $x+n$ have common difference $n$, **not** the sides of the triangle.
The correspondence to rational right triangles $(X,Y,Z)$ with $X<Y<Z$ then is
$$
(X,Y,Z)\mapsto x=(Z/2)^2,
$$
and
$$
x\mapsto (X,Y,Z)=(\sqrt{x+n}-\sqrt{x-n},\sqrt{x+n}+\sqrt{x-n},2\sqrt{x}).
$$
Conrad's [notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwidvKOS5cjPAhWMbRQKHRJqAXEQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fugradnumthy%2Fcongnumber.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGI4XewLLYc8U3U5yMALtAh8IT1Hw&sig2=2ENYX4Ux67dHNBVDlP5poQ.) are beautifully written and have all the details, e.g., section $3$. 
For $n=7$ we obtain the triangle $(\frac{24}5\,,\;\;\frac{35}{12}\;,\;\;\frac{337}{60})$. So we have
$$
(x,x-7,x+7)=\left( \left(\frac{337}{120}\right)^2, \left(\frac{113}{120}\right)^2,\left(\frac{463}{120}\right)^2\right).
$$